# How to extract unique records(rows) from a table in MS ACCESS and save them to different tables

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am working in a project in MS ACCESS 2010 where i have a existing tables lets assume employee details and i have to extract each row based on the field first_name of employee and then make a different table for each of them.For example if first name is John then i should get all the records from employee details table where first name field is John and save all these rows in a new table i.e. new table_John and so on.
For this i have created a new table with only unique records of first name field and then running the below code, but i am getting an run time error 3067 : Query input must contain at least one table or query

```
Private Sub cmdRemoveDuplicates_Click()
Dim db As Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim rst1 As Recordset
Dim tbl As Table

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tblDetails", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
'Make new table with unique records from first name field 
CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT distinct first_name INTO [unique_records] from tblDetails;"

Set rst1 = db.OpenRecordset("unique_records", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
rst1.Requery
Do Until rst1.EOF

CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT tblDetails.* INTO tblNew" & rst1!first_name & _
" FROM unique_records LEFT JOIN tblDetails ON unique_records.first_name = tblDetails.first_name" & _
" WHERE (((tblDetails.first_name)='" & rst1!first_name & "'));"



rst1.MoveNext

Loop
rst1.Close
rst.Close
db.Close
Set rst1 = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are getting a space or invalid character in there.  Add [] around the table name, and if you don't want leading/training spaces, then TRIM them out.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT tblDetails.* INTO [tblNew" & rst1!first_name & _
"] FROM unique_records LEFT JOIN tblDetails ON unique_records.first_name = tblDetails.first_name" &  _
" WHERE (((tblDetails.first_name)='" & rst1!first_name & "'));"
```

If you still get an error, assign the string in the EXECUTE to a string variable, and paste it into MS Access and see what it says.  Sometimes the problem is obvious when looking at the actual SQL.

Comment: The code worked in excel 2010 and previously i was running in excel 2013 so it might be some compatibility issue, but the code i have stated above in my problem worked finally.